# StaticInjectorError - Populating drop-down lists

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, angular6

**Angular v6.1.10 | ASP.Net Core v2.2.102**

---

I am trying to pull up data from my API to populate drop-down lists on my Angular app.

I am getting the following error and warning on the console:

**Warning**

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://localhost:5000/sockjs-node/050/xwusnroj/websocket' failed:
>   WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
>   WebSocketTransport.close @ sockjs.js:2998

**Error**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PortoService -> Http]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PortoService -> Http]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!

As shown on the image bellow:

[image: Warning and Error]

When running Karma Debugger, I am getting the following Spec List:

> CounterComponent should display a title should start with count 0,
>   then increments by 1 when clicked FishFormComponent should create
>   PortoService should be created

[image]

I am unsure why I am getting those errors. Any help is appreciated!

---

### Services

**porto.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PortoService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getPortos() {
    return this.http.get('/api/portos')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

---

### App

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { FishFormComponent } from './fish-form/fish-form.component';
import { PortoService } from './services/porto.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    FishFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      {path: 'fishes/new', component: FishFormComponent},
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin },
    PortoService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

### Form

**fish-form.components.ts**

```
import { PortoService } from './../services/porto.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fish-form',
  templateUrl: './fish-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fish-form.component.css']
})
export class FishFormComponent implements OnInit {
  portos;

  constructor(private PortoService: PortoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.PortoService.getPortos().subscribe(portos => {
      this.portos = portos;
      console.log("PORTOS", this.portos);
    });
  }

}
```

**fish-form.component.ts**

```
<h1>Adiciona um Peixe Novo</h1>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="porto">Porto</label>
    <select id="porto" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let p of portos" value="{{ p.id }}">{{ p.nome }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="especie">Especie</label>
    <select id="especie" class="form-control"></select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `@angular/http` is deprecated. See [official docs](https://angular.io/api/http) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by updating the import in porto.services.ts to, as [@ABOS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3979823/abos) suggested:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

And changing:

```
constructor(private http: Http)
```

to

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient)
```

And as `HttpClient.get()` applies `res.json()` automatically and returns `Observable<HttpResponse<string>>`, I have removed `.map(res => res.json());` as there is no need to use the map method.